# Query MySQL Linux Server From Mac

Tags: mysql

My company stores data in MySQL on a Linux server. I want to write SQL queries against that database from my Mac. What's the best free SQL client to use. Ideally, the tool would have a GUI that lets me drag / drop tables and construct SQL visually, but that's not a requirement. I can write SQL if I need to. I just prefer a more visual interface. What's the best free tool.

Answer (score 0):

[MySQL Query Browser](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/5.0.html)

[MySQL WorkBench](http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)

[Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/)